# mysql 5.7 create TEMPORARY table

Tags: mysql

Разрабатываю приложение в котором один из модулей должен выбрать свободные ресурсы из пула.

Для простоты будем считать что надо забронировать билеты в кинотеатре и надо избежать повторной продажи билетов.

Запросы при этом идут(или могут идти) параллельно

Вот работающий код, который решает эту задачу. Собственно использована  инструкция `select for update` из документации.

Мне надо бронировать по 3 билета - поэтому понадобилась временная таблица. Поскольку запросы идут паралельно - то я не могу написать просто create TEMPORARY table T1 потому что T1 будет доступна и для второго запроса.

На выходе возвращаются забронированные места.

Поэтому пришлось городить на ровном месте такой не читаемый код.

Собственно **ВОПРОС**: можно ли что то придумать чтобы улучшить читаемость кода ?
Например в MySQL 8 появились переменные типа table которые эту проблему решают

```
create table ticket_test
(
    seat  int primary key,
    count int default 0 null
);
```

Будем считать что count отображает занято место или нет (т.е. он должен быть только 0 или 1)

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE testSelForUpdate2()
BEGIN

    SELECT CONCAT('gayrat_tmp_',REPLACE(TIME(NOW()),':','_')) INTO @tbl;

    SET @str=CONCAT("create TEMPORARY table ",@tbl," (seat int)");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    START TRANSACTION;

    SET @str=CONCAT("INSERT INTO  ",@tbl," (SELECT seat FROM ticket_test where count=0 limit 3 for update)");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    DO SLEEP(10);

    SET @str=CONCAT("update ticket_test inner join  ",@tbl,"  TT on ticket_test.seat = TT.seat set count=count+1;");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    COMMIT;

    SET @str=CONCAT("select * from  ",@tbl);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо temporary table надо применить обычную таблицу вида:

```
create table if not exists ggvlasey_avito.ticket_test_tmp
(
    jobId     varchar(50)                         null,
    seat      int                                 not null,
    timestamp timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP null
);
```

Для каждого запроса при бронировании места создаем случайную переменную

```
select HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(5)) as uuid4 into curUUID;
```

Так как сверху я написал Mysql 5.7 - то встроенная функциия UUID() работает на основе времени и чисто теоретически два запроса могут прийти в один и тот же момент времени - в этом случае UUID() будет иметь одинаковое значение - например если Вы запустите такой запрос - то значения будут совершенно одинаковыми
`select UUID(),UUID()`

Запрос `select HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(5)) ,HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(5))` выдаст разные значения

На SO попался код в котором предлагают применить функцию sha2() - но здесь она совершенно лишняя - так как просто вычисляет хеш - но не генерирует случайное число.

Обновленная версия процедуры выглядит так. DO SLEEP(10) исползуется для того чтобы я успел запустить запрос в другой консоли.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE testSelForUpdate3()
BEGIN
    DECLARE curUUID varchar(60);
    select HEX(RANDOM_BYTES(5)) as uuid4 into curUUID;
#     удалить старые записи из временной таблицы
    delete from ticket_test_tmp where timestamp < timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE));


    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO ticket_test_tmp( jobId, seat)
        (SELECT curUUID, seat FROM ticket_test where count=0 limit 3 for update);

    DO SLEEP(10);

    update ticket_test
        inner join  ticket_test_tmp TT
            on ticket_test.seat = TT.seat and TT.jobId=curUUID
        set count=count+1;

    COMMIT;

    select seat from ticket_test_tmp where jobId=curUUID;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что SELECT FOR UPDATE не работает для нескольких параллельных запросов, по ощущениям прошлых опытов.

ИМХО надежнее делать временную блокировку нужного числа билетов на последнем шаге окончательного списания не в базе, а в каком-то кэше (мемкэш, рэдис и т.п.) на некоторое время и учитывать наличие заблокированных мест при выборке доступных. Важный момент в блокировке на время еще в том, что в случае если скрипт упадет или что-то пойдет не так, блокировка должна протухать, а не оставаться навечно, что может у вас произойти в базе данных.

Comment: Обратите внимание на DO SLEEP(10); В phpstorm открыл две сессии в бд и запускал запросы почти параллельно. SELECT FOR UPDATE реально работает. Если его убрать - то идет двойное букирование. Вы можете проверить это самостоятельно - весь код я привел. Кстати если не обернуть запросы в транзакцию - то тоже не работает (об этом в документации написано).  Если скрипт упадет - то транзакция по timeout откатиться вместе с блокировкой (это я конечно не смог протестировать - даже и не знаю как) Т.е. вариант реально рабочий, работает начиная с версии mysql 5.7